# Slick layout doesn't work after update the content in a section

Tags: javascript, html, layout, slick.js

Hi guys I've got some problems with slik code
After a button click, the layout in the slider no longer works and I don't know why, I guess I have to recall this function:

```
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
```

But I'm not sure and I don't know where to call it.

Some ideas?

Thanks

Denis

Comment: The `slick` tag for your question is not referring to the js carousel library. Please remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your point. I'm talking about a slider made by some dynamic contents and the Slick library

Comment: The `slick` tag you have added to your question refers to:  _Slick acronym for Scala Language-Integrated Connection Kit, is a modern database query and access library for Scala by Lightbend._

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry, I remove it immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unslick before you add any content to it,

then init it again

```
  $(".regular").slick("unslick");
  $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
        //attr you need
      });
```

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be useful, but actually when I call slick("unslick") the layout of the page is destroyed...

If you are so kind to verify yourself here:
http://dbspace.altervista.org/slickTest/slider_dynamic.html

When you click on the "Change content" button, you can see the layout destroying itself...

Comment: It appered that your page refreshed after clicking the filter,perhaps you should try using ajax to call new data.